# Wrapping body content with jQuery breaks page

Tags: jquery

I want to wrap a site's content in a div (I'm writing a plugin that the user would agree to this happening). I'm doing that like this:

`jQuery("body").append(jQuery('<div id="site-content"></div>')); jQuery("body").children(':not(#site-content)').wrap(jQuery('#site-content'));`

For some reason, it breaks on this site:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/

Why is this, and is there a way around that?

**EDIT**

Ok, `$.wrap` is not quite what I wanted, but even if you just move the content using `appendTo` it still doesn't work.

Example:

`jQuery("body").append(jQuery('<div id="site-content"></div>')); jQuery("body").children(':not(#site-content)').appendTo(jQuery('#site-content'))`

This is what happens (what I mean by breaking the site)
[image]

Here's code that works without jQuery:

```
var contentWrapper, contentContainer, ps_header, node, domSkip = 0, disallowedTags = {
    "SCRIPT": null,
    "STYLE": null
};

//Create contentWrapper
(contentWrapper = document.createElement("div")).className = document.body.className + " content-wrapper";
(contentContainer = document.createElement("div")).className = "content-container";
contentWrapper.appendChild(contentContainer);

//Populate contentWrapper with the body, while removing it from the body
while (document.body.children.length > domSkip) {
    node = document.body.children[domSkip];

    if (node.nodeName in disallowedTags) {

        domSkip++;
        continue;
    }

    document.body.removeChild(node);
    contentContainer.appendChild(node);
}

//Now drop contentWrapper into the DOM
document.body.appendChild(contentWrapper);
```

Comment: what do you mean with "breaks page"?

Comment: execute that in the console on that page and you'll see

Comment: it's no error, it breaks the site

Answer (score 1):

Use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)

```
$('body').wrapInner('<div id="site-content"></div>');
```

Comment: breaks the site as well